# Need help to install No-IP DUC

Tags: software-installation, make

I cannot install No-IP Dynamic Update Client (No-IP DUC) as it says `command make not found`. I have not tried anything as I could not find anything online.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Secondly, `make` comes with the `build-essential` package.  `sudo apt install build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install make
```

If that doesn't work see [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/).

Comment: You'll still need `build-essential` for things like the C compiler, etc too.